# Get data from a ListView item and send to another activity (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I am trying to send this object information to another activity with intent. All information is in this picture.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i am beginner,sorry my bad English :(

Answer (score 0):

First Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putSerializable("VALUE", listItem);
```

Second Activity

```
Intent intent=this.getIntent();
Object list = intent.getSerializable("VALUE");
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please change Object to GeoLabStudent
>
> you should use adapter's reference to get item

GeoLabStudent object = (GeoLabStudent)geoLabAdapter.getItem(position);

> Make your model GeoLabStudent to serializable or parcelable for sending your object to other activity

[Example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/01/android-tutorial-two-methods-of-passing-object-by-intent-serializableparcelable.html)